# How long does activity record live in the OS?

Tags: android

It is said that we can preserve data on `Activity`'s death by overriding `onSaveInstanceState()`. All data we put there will be saved somewhere in the OS.

My question is - for how long will OS hold that data? Is it predictable at all?

Comment: its a temporary data kept by system till it recreates the Activity again

Comment: You're correct. But I was wondering about the time span or certain event which would trigger the OS to delete said temporary data.

Comment: i guess it deletes that temp Bundle after onRestoreInstanceState completes

Comment: **"Is it predictable at all?"** Almost certainly not. Why do you want to know this anyway?

Comment: The thing which boggles me is that Bundle may not be there when we need it if transition took long enough and outlived the Bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, it has already been a better discussion: [Saving Activity state in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android?rq=1)

In any case, the topic seem to be a controversy since the life span of transient state data is not very well defined, nor can it be predicted.

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't be thinking about these kinds of things as these are the states of **event driven** data. The Event is you are transitioning activities and leaving the activity, which will execute the onPause() in which cause you store your data in the onSaveInstanceState() and during the onResume() restore your data from the bundle from onRestoreInstanceState().

If you are TRULY worried about this, then consider storing your data permanently in your app space like SharedPerferences  or some local file.

Also a little FYI, if your are thinking about this, have you considered that **perhaps what you're doing is bad design**?